# Android cloudinary async uploader error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary for uploading images.

When I tried to do it in `onCreate` it gave error obvious error of `NetworkOnMainThread`. So now I tried using `AsyncTask`, But now it results in `NPE`.

```
09-12 23:36:18.443: E/AndroidRuntime(24715): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 23:36:18.443: E/AndroidRuntime(24715):    at com.example.dbms.UploadActivity$Upload.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:51)
```

And the code in view is as below :

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
Cloudinary cloudinary;
JSONObject Result;
String file_path;
File file;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    file_path = i.getStringExtra("file");
    HashMap config = new HashMap();
    config.put("cloud_name", "dbms");
    config.put("api_key", "key");//I have changed the key and secret
    config.put("api_secret", "secret");
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
    textView.setText(file_path);
    file = new File(file_path);
}

private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            Result = cloudinary.uploader().upload(file,
                    Cloudinary.emptyMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        textView.setText("file uploaded");
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Upload task = new Upload();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.com" });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.upload, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The line in concern is :

```
Result = cloudinary.uploader().upload(file,
                    Cloudinary.emptyMap());
```

Comment: Find out what's null (probably `cloudinary`) and make sure it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined `cloudinary` twice -- once in the class, and once in `onCreate()`. When you assign a value to the one in `onCreate()` the `cloudinary` member in the class remains null, so your app crashes. It would be best to pass the instance into the AsyncTask, such as:

In `onCreate()` change

```
Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
```

to

```
cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
```

Change `Upload` to:

```
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Cloudinary mCloudinary;

    public Upload( Cloudinary cloudinary ) {
        super();
        mCloudinary = cloudinary;
    }
```

and in `doInBackground()`, change:

```
Result = cloudinary.uploader().upload(file,
                    Cloudinary.emptyMap());
```

to

```
Result = mCloudinary.uploader().upload(file,
                    Cloudinary.emptyMap());
```

Finally, change your `onClick()` from

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Upload task = new Upload();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.com" });

}
```

to

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Upload task = new Upload( cloudinary );
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.com" });

}
```